# Convert current PDO Function to MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay so i have been using PDO for all my practice projects where i also made a PDO class. Now what i want to do is make a MYSQLI version of the class but i am having trouble understanding how to use MYSQLI Prepared statements in this function:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $this->_error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count   = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see this has only been partly converted i am having trouble understanding where to do from here. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

mysqli uses bind_param($str, $param1, $param2, ...)

where $str is a concatenation of types (one char each, 'i', 'd', 's', or 'b'.  see the manual link above)

i.e. `bind_param('sss', $string1, $string2, $string3);`

if all your params are the same type you could use str_repeat based on count($params) to generate this.  else you'll have to do something a bit more complex to get the types.

Comment: What about fetching and binding the results as an object? Or is the bind param the only thing I need to change here.

Comment: Yes, sorry I neglected to finish this by also altering your results.  You will want to do a similar bind_result() call (without the type string .  mysqli_stmt->fetch() will fetch one row at a time into your bound variables.  (fetch_all is not supported on mysqli statements.)  see the example in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php : ``$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);  while ($stmt->fetch()) { ... } ``

Comment: for your row count you can count the iterations of the while loop, or you can tell PHP to buffer the results using $this->_query->store_result(), then access $this->_query->num_rows;    http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php